# Sliders and List Plots

Tags: plotting

I need to create a list plot of 3 different values that can be controlled by sliders. I have the sliders but I have no idea how to get those values to show up as points on a plot.

```
Manipulate[I + V + R, {I, -10, 10}, {V, -10, 10}, {R, 0, 1000}, 
 ControlType -> {Slider, Slider, Slider}]
```

Answer (score 2):

For there to be points, you presumably want 2D sliders.

Points are made different sizes so that they are not totally obscured when they overlap.

```
Manipulate[
 Legended[
  Graphics[{
    AbsolutePointSize[10],
    Black, Tooltip[Point[i + v + r], i + v + r], 
    AbsolutePointSize[8],
    Red, Tooltip[Point[i], i],
    AbsolutePointSize[6],
    Blue, Tooltip[Point[v], v],
    AbsolutePointSize[4],
    Darker[Green], Tooltip[Point[r], r]},
   Frame -> True,
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   PlotRange -> All,
   ImageSize -> 300],
  PointLegend[
   {Red, Blue, Darker[Green], Black},
   {"I", "V", "R", "I+V+R"}]],
 Row[{
   Control[{{i, {-10, -10}, "I"},
     {-10, -10}, {10, 10}}],
   Spacer[25],
   Control[{{v, {5, 5}, "V"},
     {-10, -10}, {10, 10}}],
   Spacer[25],
   Control[{{r, {20, 20}, "R"},
     {0, 0}, {1000, 1000}}]}]]
```

[image]

If the intent is just to have points along a number line

```
Manipulate[
 Legended[
  Graphics[{
    AbsolutePointSize[10],
    Black, Tooltip[Point[{i + v + r, 0}], i + v + r],
    AbsolutePointSize[8],
    Red, Tooltip[Point[{i, 0}], i],
    AbsolutePointSize[6],
    Blue, Tooltip[Point[{v, 0}], v],
    AbsolutePointSize[4],
    Darker[Green], Tooltip[Point[{r, 0}], r]},
   Frame -> {True, False, False, False},
   AspectRatio -> 1/10,
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}},
   ImageSize -> 300],
  Placed[
   PointLegend[
    {Red, Blue, Darker[Green], Black},
    {"I", "V", "R", "I+V+R"},
    LegendLayout -> "Row"],
   Bottom]],
 {{i, -10, "I"}, -10, 10, 0.1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{v, 5, "V"}, -10, 10, 0.1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r, 20, "R"}, 0, 1000, 10,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]